# PHP / MySQL, not understanding foreach loop in this particular case. [conceptual Q]

Tags: php, mysql, object-oriented-analysis

Before I ask my question, I will post the code:  (Please note if you can just explain the second question it'll be sufficient, I am just really confused what's happening at the foreach loop.

```
<?php
class dbh {
    private $servername; private $username; private $password; private $ 
    dbname;
    protected function connect() {
    $this->servername = "localhost";
    $this->username = "root";
    $this->password = "";
    $this->dbname = "whatever";

    $conn = new mysqli($this->servername, $this->username, $this->password, 
$this->dbname);
    return $conn;
    }
}

<?php
class User extends Dbh {
    protected function getAllUsers() {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM user";
        $result = $this->connect()->query($sql);
        $numRows = $result->num_rows;
        if($numRows > 0) {
           while($row = $result ->fetch_assoc()) {
               $data[] = $row;
           }
           return $data;
        }
    }
}

<?php
class ViewUser extends User {
   public function showAllUsers() {
      $datas = $this->getAllUsers();
      foreach ($datas as $data) {
         echo $data['uid'] . "<br>";
         echo $data['pwd'] . "<br>";
      }
   }
}

<?php
    includes all those classes
?>

<body>
<?php
    $users = new ViewUser();
    $users->showAllUsers();
?>
</body>
```

I don't understand a couple things about this code.

1. Firstly, what is "this" in those classes?  It is just a placeholder for the users object, which is the current object, right?  I think it is.
2. Secondly, and my main question, when we call the member function showAllUsers(), we go to the ViewUser class, and then we have a $datas variable that gets assigned to $this->getAllUsers() which ends up returning a $data array, which contains all the rows in the database...  Right?

Then my question is, what are the contents of $datas in the foreach loop?  Is it an array of rows?  $data is supposed to be key values, but $data is also an array which has me very confused.

I am visualizing it like $datas = $data, so 
$datas[] = [$data[0], $data[1], $data[2], $data[3], ... $data[last_one]]
and each one of these elements contains a row ...
So foreach($datas as data) goes through each element, but to display it we need to echo data[0]?
Is my understanding correct?  I know it's an associative array so those 0, 1, 2... etc are the column titles of table..

3. Also, what exactly does $fetch_assoc do when we have $row = fetch_assoc?  Are we just storing rows in the $rows variable?  The while loop is false when we reach the last row, right?  I'm just so used to seeing a conditional in a while loop, like for instance while (x == 4).  I have never seen a situation where we assign a variable, like for example while (x = 4) until now.

Comment: The code above is OOP, which is object oriented programming. It is different than procedural. In procedural you can build code in a linear manner while OO you build code based on objects. I’m on my phone so I cannot type out the rest right now- but once I get to my PC I’ll answer unless someone else has by then. Also in classes what you’re calling variables are called attributes, and what you’re used to calling functions are called methods inside of the classes.

Comment: I see someone else has answered. I will tell you this- while you’re taking the dive into OOP, forget about MySQLi and learn to use PDO.

Comment: You have to study more OOP (Object oriented programming) before asking this questions. I think stackoverflow is "not a place to learn about OPP" but to make specific questions that aren't related to the basic OOP learning process.

Comment: I had to ask, there just wasn't a good enough explanation anywhere online, I guess they are questions experts assume I'd figure out but I just needed some confirmation so I can continue.

Comment: I would say try the PHP chat room but we’re going to say read and study if you ask there as well, but at least you don’t risk being restricted from asking question for a while if you ask in chat. Just make your questions specific in chat and not so broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually quite poor for a class handling scheme, but your questions are still valid.

1. You're sort of right. `$this` is a reference to the current instance (read: object) of the class where you define a method that uses the `this` keyword.
2. Correct in all cases. You're also right in that `datas` is an array of arrays (which represents the rows in the database table). Each element of `$datas` contains another array that represents a single row where each element is a column of that row. They're associative arrays so the index is a key, like you said.
3. As per [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php), `mysqli::query` returns an object of type `mysqli_result`, so you can't access it directly as an array. `mysqli::fetch_assoc` will convert the `mysqli_result` into an associative array, row by row by moving a pointer, which is why you keep looping in the `while` loop until `fetch_assoc` returns false (that is, when no more rows are in the result object, or when the pointer reaches the last row).